# Where should I store libraries in a good Django project structure?

Tags: python, django

In one of the apps of my Django site I require a third-party module/library. I've been reading up on how a good Django project should be structured but it doesn't mention much about storing libraries. My current project is structured like so:

```
urls.py
manage.py
settings.py
apps
    app1
        views.py
        models.py
        manager.py
        tests.py
    app2
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Should a create a directory at the top-level named `libs` and dump it there or should I create a `libs` directory under the specific app folder that I'll be using this in?

Another thing was that when I code Django, I try and keep my views, models and managers very light. If some complex stuff is needed, I create a class/module and dump stuff there. Should I put this in the specific app folder that I'll be using this in or should this go to `libs` folder as well? I often have a helpers.py file in my apps but I use that for generally storing quite small and simple helper functions.

One could obviously put the library anywhere. It's all the same to Python but not necessarily the right way to go about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a third-party library, it shouldn't be kept in your source code at all.

If you use `virtualenv`, you get a complete environment that you can install libraries in specifically for that project. Plus, in conjunction with `pip`, you can set up a `requirements.txt` file which specifies all the libraries you need to run the project, and installs them in one go when you start on a new machine, or deploy to production.